# How to run complex shell command in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, github, terminal, command

How can I run the below command in Python 3.8 and get the output?

Command:

```
git remote show [URL for remote Github repo] | sed -n '/HEAD branch/s/.*: //p'
```

Command purpose:

To get the default branch from remote Github repo
also trying to run this outside git directory

Below are the commands I have tried till now, but it gives error: "*fatal: not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git*":

```
import os
p = os.system("git remote show https://github.com/docker/compose | grep 'HEAD branch' | cut -d' ' -f5")
```

```
import subprocess

subprocess.run(["git", "remote", "show", "https://github.com/docker/compose", "|", "grep", "'HEAD branch'", "|", "cut", "-d' '", "-f5" ])
```

I need the command to execute even outside the Git directory, please help me

Answer (score 1):

To run a command you can use [subprocess.run](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.run) which can return all the information you want.

But if you just want information from git use a ready-made module like [GitPython](https://gitpython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html) instead

Comment: subprocess.run did not work, if you know the exact command to execute please share

Comment: What is the error ?

Comment: error: fatal: not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
I fixed it using **git init** but it will create .git directory which i don't want is there any way to execute this without creating a .git directory?

Comment: Did you try to execute the command in the terminal? At the same level / folder where you run the Python program?
And no, most Git commands require a local repository, including the one in the question